# how to subtract two time in sql server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

So I don't know how to subtract two `time(hh:mm:ss)` in sql server.

This is my statement:

```
where   
 ( CONVERT(TIME(7), [EndWork], 102)) - ( CONVERT(TIME(7), [StartWork], 102)) <
 CONVERT(TIME(7), ' 8:30:00', 102)
```

Comment: Unfortunately, SQL Server doesn't have a data type that represents a time *interval*. I'd strongly suggest you *not* use `time` to store such values, since it represents a *time of day*, and therefore isn't very useful for intervals (doesn't allow negative values, doesn't support values greater than 24 hours). So even once you've performed your subtracting, I wouldn't recommend trying to compare that to `CONVERT(TIME(7), ' 8:30:00', 102)`.

Comment: This has nothing to do with ASP.NET MVC.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever - The OP doesn't state that he's storing time intervals, just time values.  From the context, it looks like he might be storing the date/time work began and the date/time work ended. It may be that it's impossible for his system to maintain an interval greater than 24 hours, so no harm done.

Comment: @STLDev - they're subtracting one time from another and expecting to still work with it as a "time". When I subtract one time from another, I expect to end up with an interval. What do you expect?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
DECLARE @END_DATE TIME = '' ,    
     @START_DATE  TIME = ''
     SELECT CONVERT(TIME,DATEADD(MS,DATEDIFF(SS, @START_DATE, @END_DATE )*1000,0),114)
```

Answer (score 19):

Using the [DATEDIFF](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189794.aspx)  function you will get the difference of two dates/time in Year/Month/Day/Hour/Min/Sec as you required.

Eg:- `DATEDIFF ( MINUTE , startdate , enddate )` --will return the diff in minutes

Answer (score 8):

You can try to use the [DATEDIFF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189794.aspx) function like this:

```
where DATEDIFF(HH,StartWork, EndWork)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select CONVERT(varchar,DATEADD(MS,DATEDIFF(SS, started_at_date, ended_at_date )*1000,0),8)
```

Comment: Please make more obvious what additional insight your post provides. With its lack of any explanation, it is otherwise not clear why you think that this code-only solution is worth another post. Ideally explain the subtle advantage which your approach has over the existing other solutions.

Comment: here you don't need to use any variables. also, it will take less space than time conversion.

Comment: Your explanation belongs in the answer, not a comment.

Comment: Please explain how you achieve that no variables are needed, especially in contrast to those other existing answers which are not using `@END_DATE` and `@START_DATE` either. Please provide supporting info for your claim that your solution needs less space. Please do all explaining inside the answer itself, by [edit]ing it.