# Sum of all the time in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I used the below line in the select statement which results in the Total number of Hours

```
CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),out_time - in_time, 108) [TOTAL_TIME]
```

```
In_time      Out_time   Total_time
1:00:00      2:00:00    1:00:00
2:15:00      3:00:00    0:45:00
2:00:00      2:15:00    0:00:15
```

I would like to get the sum of total Hours from `Total_time`

How can we achieve this? I have attached the below as an example

```
In_time     Out_time    Total_time  Sum_of_Total
1:00:00     2:00:00     1:00:00     1:45:15
2:15:00     3:00:00     0:45:00     1:45:15
2:00:00     2:15:00     0:00:15     1:45:15
```

Comment: Please confirm what data type the two timestamps are.

Comment: If your columns, `out_time` and `in_time` are a `time` (which would seem a logical assumption for them to be be) then your expression `out_time - in_time` is going to error; you can't take a `time` away from another, they aren't numbers. To get the difference in 2 date and/or time values, you should be using `DATEDIFF`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to subtract two time in sql server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36906896/how-to-subtract-two-time-in-sql-server)

Answer (score 0):

the calculation of row of Total_time in your table is wrong. it does yield minutes not seconds.thus, Sum_of_Total would be 02:00:00 not 1:45:15

your table

```
declare @a TABLE (
   In_time    time NOT NULL 
  ,Out_time   time NOT NULL
);
INSERT INTO @a(In_time,Out_time) VALUES ('1:00:00','2:00:00');
INSERT INTO @a(In_time,Out_time) VALUES ('2:15:00','3:00:00');
INSERT INTO @a(In_time,Out_time) VALUES ('2:00:00','2:15:00');
```

getting total_time

```
select In_time,Out_time,
CONVERT(varchar(12), DATEADD(minute, DATEDIFF(minute, In_time, Out_time), 0), 114) Total_time
from @a
```

calculation of Sum_of_Total

```
with t as(
select In_time,Out_time,
CONVERT(varchar(12), DATEADD(minute, DATEDIFF(minute, In_time, Out_time), 0), 114) Total_time
from @a
)
select In_time,Out_time,Total_time
,(select cast(DATEADD(SS, SUM(DATEDIFF(ss, '00:00:00', Total_time)), '00:00:00') as time) from t) as Sum_of_Total
from t
```